# No podspec found for `ActionCableClient`. Pod installation issue

Tags: ios, xcode, github, cocoapods, xcode10.1

I'm trying to install the pod [ActionCableClient](https://github.com/danielrhodes/Swift-ActionCableClient) to my project but after pod installation, I was getting many errors due to which I was unable to build. So, I tried downloading their sample and run the project after installing the pod and that worked well. When I checked their pod file it also had a path mentioned. So, I tried the same Podfile contents to my project, below is how my Podfile looks now.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

def common_pods
  pod 'ActionCableClient', :path => '../'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'SnapKit'
end

def common_test_pods
  pod 'Quick', '~> 0.9.3'
  pod 'Nimble', '3.2.0'
end

target 'ActionCableTest' do
  common_pods
end
```

But when I try to do a pod install it's giving me the error

> No podspec found for `ActionCableClient` in `../`

But strange enough it works well for the sample app provided by them. Am I missing something here? Do I need to add anything else in project settings? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you add 'ActionCable' target for main target of project in podfile?

Comment: My project name is ActionCableTest, for the tests it will be ActionCableTestTests

Comment: Okay, i'll edit my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ActionCableTest is your main target, check this;

```
use_frameworks!

def common_pods
  pod "ActionCableClient"
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'SnapKit'
end

def common_test_pods
  pod 'Quick', '~> 0.9.3'
  pod 'Nimble', '3.2.0'
end

target 'ActionCableTest' do
  common_pods
end
```

If you want set specific target

```
 pod 'ActionCableClient', :git => 'https://github.com/danielrhodes/Swift-ActionCableClient.git'
```

If you want set specific target with tag

```
 pod 'ActionCableClient', :git => 'https://github.com/danielrhodes/Swift-ActionCableClient.git', :tag => 'v0.2.3'
```

If you want set path

```
pod 'ActionCableClient', :path => 'RawPods/'
```

and RawPods folder contain ActionCableClient folder. After that ActionCableClient folder contain .**podspec** file

Answer (score 2):

The only change you will make --> :path => to :git =>

```
use_frameworks!

def common_pods
  pod 'ActionCableClient', :git => 'https://github.com/danielrhodes/Swift-ActionCableClient.git'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'SnapKit'
end

def common_test_pods
  pod 'Quick', '~> 0.9.3'
  pod 'Nimble', '3.2.0'
end

target 'ActionCableTest' do
  common_pods
end
```

I hope this is works for you.

Or you can set your path like this:

```
pod 'ActionCableClient', :path => '~/Path/Of/ActionCableClient'
```

Enjoy.